# how get a vars-data-myvar into google analytics variable

Tags: google-analytics

I have the follw code in my site:

```
<a class="click" data-vars-myvars="my values" href="..." >linktext</a>
```

I have a trigger on the class in Analytics. So far so good. But now I wan't the value from `data-vars-myvars` as a variable in Analytics (Web-Version). How can I do it?
Note: In the AMP Version of Analytics is it no problem there is a predefined var for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with var for auto events:
[image]